# how to predict with restored model by multi-process

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have saved the training model.

the predict code is as follow:

```
def predict(predict_filename):
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        # normalization image
         ...
        im_norm = tf.image.per_image_standardization(rgb_image)

        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        with sess.as_default():

            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord, sess=sess)

            def get_ckpt():
                ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
                return ckpt

            ckpt = get_ckpt()

            def get_saver():
                new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path + '.meta')
                return new_saver

            new_saver = get_saver()

            if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
                print(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
                new_saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
                try:
                    while not coord.should_stop():

                         result = sess.run("Linear_regression/Add:0", feed_dict={'conv1/Reshape:0': image_new.eval(),                                                                         'dropout2/dropout/keep_prob:0': 0.2})
                        ...
                except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                    print('Done training after reading all data')
                finally:  # When done, ask the threads to stop.
                    coord.request_stop()
                    # Wait for threads to finish.
                    # tf.reset_default_graph()
                    coord.join(threads)
                    sess.close()
                    # os._exit(0)
            else:
                print('no checkpoint found')
```

I used starmap multi process to get predict value:

```
 def main(argv=None):  
        filename = []
        filename.append('./1.jpg')
        filename.append('./2.jpg')
        filename.append('./3.jpg')
        filename = np.array(filename).astype(str)
        print(filename)
        pool = ThreadPool(1)
        pool.starmap(predict, zip(filename))
        pool.join()
        pool.close()
```

here I only used one process. Run the project, the predict value for "1.jpg" can get successfully, then get the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value file_queue/limit_epochs/epochs
     [[Node: file_queue/limit_epochs/CountUpTo = CountUpTo[T=DT_INT64, _class=["loc:@file_queue/limit_epochs/epochs"], limit=40, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](file_queue/limit_epochs/epochs)]]
```

I really do not know why the predict for second picture get the error ,but the first can get the right result?

When I add   os._exit(0) in "finally",everything goes well, three pictures all can get the right result ,why?

If add if I add sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()), after predict first picture, then get the log:Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\IQA\paralle_test.py", line 109, in predict
    getvalue(file)
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\IQA\paralle_test.py", line 104, in getvalue
    print('no checkpoint found')
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1208, in __exit__
    self._default_graph_context_manager.__exit__(exec_type, exec_value, exec_tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3520, in get_controller
    if self.stack[-1] is not default:
IndexError: list index out of range
"""\tensor
flo
```

Comment: Could you examine the output carefully and check that you didn't get a memory exhaustion error?

Comment: @drpng I am sure the memory is enough, and didn't get any log related to that.

Comment: You need a `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` after you create the session. Also, I'm not sure that you can run nested sessions, so I would try with that.

Comment: if I add sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()), after predict first picture, then get the error"no check point found". The whole log i update the question.

Comment: @drpng I think there is something wrong with graph init, but I do not find correct way to solve it , need your help~

Comment: @drpng I delete the top session, everything go well , and don't need to  add "sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())"

Comment: Glad to see it works for you!